# Double digit numeric range regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to write a regex to match for Severity Errors 17 - 25, looking at the error log. (I can provide the full code necessary to get the error log records into a staging table for processing, but I figured it wasn't necessary in relation to the regex)

The closest I've been able to get is...

```
...
where [Message] like '%Severity: [12][789012345]%'
...
```

...however, this will end up matching severity errors like 12, 13, 14, 15.. due to the combination of the 1 in the first set + the other digits in the second set.

I ended up just writing a set of `like` statements to achieve it...

```
...
where [Message] like '%Severity: 17%' 
    or [Message] like '%Severity: 18%' 
    or [Message] like '%Severity: 19%'
    or [Message] like '%Severity: 20%'
    or [Message] like '%Severity: 21%'
    or [Message] like '%Severity: 22%'
    or [Message] like '%Severity: 23%'
    or [Message] like '%Severity: 24%'
    or [Message] like '%Severity: 25%'
```

Unfortunately SQL Server regex is quite limited, so I can't use the full standard.

Note, even if the execution plan is the same between a regex and multiple `like` statements, I'd much prefer to use a regex for the sake of code brevity, it looks much cleaner.. unless the performance of multiple `like` statements is better, in which case I'd prefer performance, as I'm often looking at client's logs with hundreds of thousands or millions of rows.

Is it possible to write a SQL Server regex for a numeric range 17 - 25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to write a SQL Server regex for a numeric range 17 -
> 25?

Not with native TSQL.

You could write a CLR function to do this though.

Using native TSQL string functions you could potentially parse out the severity value and then test it.

```
WHERE  TRY_CONVERT(INT, 
                   SUBSTRING([Message], 
                             NULLIF(PATINDEX('%Severity: [1-2][0-9]%', [Message] ) + 10, 0), 
                             2)
                   ) BETWEEN 17 AND 25
```

Another alternative to access proper Regex is via the Java [language extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/language-extensions-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) but I've never gone that route myself.

Comment: Sorry @martin - I started a comment then changed my mind but accidentally posted that.

Comment: Appreciated @martin, I hadn't thought of parsing the message like that!